# Google Tag Manager - Enhanced Ecommerce and ajax

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my product page detail, i have a crosselling section which loads a product list when user scroll down. I can trigger a custom event when products in this section are loads (like productsDowloaded). 
How can i send product impressions with google tag manager ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement the data layer following [these specifications](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions) to track product impressions. If you are sending the data asynchronously, push an event to the data layer (eg: event: 'crossSellReady') and fire your custom event GA tag with a rule based on event = crossSellReady. In the custom event tag, make sure to enable enhanced eCommerce tracking, and the tag should automatically pick up the product impression data contained in the data layer. Let me know if you encounter any issue.

Comment: Tag configuration fire by this event (crossSellReady) should be : Track type : Pageview or Track type : Pageview or Track type : Event ?

Comment: Both would work, but I would recommend firing a custom event to avoid inflating your pageview metrics. You just need to fill in the event action and event label you want to associate with your custom event. You can have the category = 'Cross Sell', action = 'Cross Sell Widget Impression' for instance.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is first loaded the first batch of cross sell products are pushed to the *dataLayer* as impressions and a GA pageview is sent. The GA pageview is a simple GA tag that is fired after the page is loaded.

After that, when the cross sell products are loaded asynchronously, i.e. whenever the user scrolls down, only *those* products are pushed to the *dataLayer* and a custom *dataLayer* event is fired in the success handler of the ajax request. For example:

```
// Inside Ajax success handler...
dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'Custom'
 'eventCategory': 'ecommerce',
 'eventAction': 'ajax-load'
 'eventLabel': 'cross sell'
});
```

You create a separate generic GA tag that sends events and is fired when the `Custom` event is pushed to the dataLayer. Inside the generic GA event tag you set all the of the following macros which are of type *dataLayer variable*:

1. {{event category}} -> `eventCategory`
2. {{event action}} -> `eventAction`
3. {{event label}} -> `eventLabel`

You can also add a `nonInteraction` macro in the generic GA event tag as well. Your use case, in my opinion, is considered a user interaction (user scrolled down) so the *nonInteraction* macro should not be set.

If you are using product lists, be careful of the positions of the cross sell items. Whenever those products are asynchronously loaded, you should note down their positions so you can track their positions in the product list tab of the GA dashboard correctly.

P.S. The generic GA event tag has multiple benefits, you can find more information about what I'm saying by reading the relevant [article](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/create-a-generic-event-tag/) in Simo Ahava's blog.